# Python standard idiom to set sys.stdout buffer to zero doesn't work with Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, buffer, stdout

When I'm writing sysadmin scripts in Python, the buffer on sys.stdout that effects every call to print() is annoying, because I don't want to wait for a buffer to be flushed and then get a big chunk of lines at once on the screen, instead I want to get individually lines of output as soon as new output is generated by the script. I don't even want to wait for newlines so see the output.

An often used idiom to do this in python is

```
import os
import sys
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
```

This worked fine for me for a long time. Now I noticed, that it doesn't work with Unicode. Please see the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

import os
import sys

print('Original encoding: {}'.format(sys.stdout.encoding))
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
print('New encoding: {}'.format(sys.stdout.encoding))

text = b'Eisb\xe4r'
print(type(text))
print(text)

text = text.decode('latin-1')
print(type(text))
print(text)
```

This leads to the following output:

```
Original encoding: UTF-8
New encoding: None
<type 'str'>
Eisb▒r
<type 'unicode'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./export_debug.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It took me hours to track down the reason for it (my original script was much longer than this minimal debugging script). It is the line

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
```

which I used for years so didn't expect any problem with it. Just comment out this line and the correct output should look like this:

```
Original encoding: UTF-8
New encoding: UTF-8
<type 'str'>
Eisb▒r
<type 'unicode'>
Eisbär
```

So what is the script ment to do? To prepare my Python 2.7 code as close as possible to Python 3.x, I'm always using

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
```

which makes python use the new print()-function but more important: it makes Python store all strings as Unicode internally by default. I have a lot of Latin-1 / ISO-8859-1 encoded data, for example

```
text = b'Eisb\xe4r'
```

To work with it the intended way, I need to decode it to Unicode first, that's what

```
text = text.decode('latin-1')
```

is for. As the default encoding is UTF-8 on my system, whenever I print a string, python encodes the internal Unicode string to UTF-8 then. But first it has to be in perfect Unicode internally.

Now that all works fine in general, just not with a zero byte output buffer so far. Any ideas? I noticed that sys.stdout.encoding is unset after the zero-buffering line, but I don't know how to set it again. It is a read-only attribute and the OS environment variables LC_ALL or LC_CTYPE seem to be evaluated only at the start of the python interpreter.

Btw.: 'Eisbär' is the German word for 'polar bear'.

Comment: @martineau Well, the sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout) proposal doesn't work either. I really tried and searched a lot. So I guess ideas without having tested them don't help much.

Comment: I've migrated the question for you. Next time, just `flag` for moderator attention and tell us what you need! :)

Comment: @MartenLehmann: The fact that it was untested is why I posted it as a comment rather an answer.

Comment: have you considered: `alias python="python -u"` *without* modifying sys.stdout. btw, codecs.getwriter... works iff you (and all libraries you use) print *only* Unicode text (so it is not recommended to use in general).

Answer (score 6):

The print function uses a special flag when writing to a file object, causing the `PyFile_WriteObject` function of the Python C API to retrieve the output encoding to do the unicode-to-bytes conversion, and by replacing the `stdout` stream you lost the encoding. Unfortunately, you cannot explicitly set it again:

```
encoding = sys.stdout.encoding
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
sys.stdout.encoding = encoding  # Raises a TypeError; readonly attribute
```

You also cannot use the [`io.open` function](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.open) instead, since it doesn't allow buffering to be disabled if you want to be able to use the `encoding` option you'd require.

The proper way to have the print function flush immediately is to use the `flush=True` keyword:

```
print(something, flush=True)
```

If that's too tedious to add everywhere, consider using a *custom* print function:

```
def print(*args, **kw):
    flush = kw.pop('flush', True)  # Python 2.7 doesn't support the flush keyword..   
    __builtins__.print(*args, **kw)
    if flush:
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Since Python 2.7's `print()` function doesn't actually *support* the flush keyword yet (botheration), you can simulate that by adding an explicit flush instead in that custom version.

Comment: You can replace three first lines of your custom `print()` function with this: `flush = kw.pop('flush', True)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `b` in the `'wb'` argument of `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)` says that the file should be in [opened](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in **binary mode**, that's why Unicode would not work. Additionally, in Python 3 I cannot print normal strings to a standard output configured that way; it says `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

For the mentioned use case of "sysadmin scripts", it should be enough to use **line buffering**, i.e. the output is flushed whenever a newline is written, such as at the end of every normal `print("mytext")` statement. For line buffering, it suffices to write:

```
import os
import sys

sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 1)  # 1 : line buffered
```

I found this to be necessary in order to have line-by-line output in case the standard output is redirected to a pipe (simplest case: `./myprogram.py | cat`) that may be read by another program.

If you need immediate flushing of parts of lines, you may use:

```
print("mytext", end="", flush=True)
```